# how to auto submit a rails 3.1 remote form every 'x' seconds?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, submit

I am trying to submit a form like this on a Ruby on Rails site:

```
var autosave = window.setInterval("autosaveForm()", 5000);

function autosaveForm() {
  $("#myForm").trigger("submit.rails");
}
```

It does submit every 5 seconds my form, however, it does not update the parameters sent by the form. For example if I start typing in a textarea that belongs to the form, when it auto-submits it won't send what I just typed as part of the parameters, it will only send the default value of the textarea or whatever it had when I first loaded the page.

If I am not being clear or you need more data please let me know.

Also, yes, my form does have :remote => 'true'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens if you trigger the regular submit function?  `$("#myForm").submit()`.  It will still be captures by the js (same as because the enter key works), and may parse the data again

Comment: That works just about the same as I described in my original problem.

Comment: this is very strange.  If you manually resubmit the form, it doesn't send with new data?

Comment: If I click a submit data buttom then it does submit the new data.

Comment: What does that button do?  What if you call $("#myForm").submit() from the console?

Answer (score 1):

You can use periodically_call_remote

for ex

```
<%= periodically_call_remote(
:url => url,
:frequency => 60,  # seconds
:update => 'div id') %>
```

Comment: I got excited about this but this is deprecated as of Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

ok you can try this for rails 3

```
$(document).ready(
 function(){
   setInterval(function(){
     $('#mydiv').load('/controller/action');
   }, 1000);
 });
```